# Session hijacking security

Tags: php, security, session

So I have a few different ways to try and prevent session hijacking, one uses the `HTTP_USER_AGENT` and detects if it has changed during a session.  The problem with this is, if a user goes to the website on a mobile phone, and changes from the mobile view to a desktop view, the user agent changes and the user gets the following error:

```
if (isset($_SESSION['HTTP_USER_AGENT']))
{
    if ($_SESSION['HTTP_USER_AGENT'] != md5($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']))
    {
        echo "Error: security issue #1 (Please use contact us if recieving this error)";
        exit;
    }
}
else
{
    $_SESSION['HTTP_USER_AGENT'] = md5($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']);
}
```

Now I still want this small layer of security, but i don't want an error message appearing and i want the site to remain viewable to the user.  How should i do this?

Comment: "I want to keep checking that the User Agent matches, but sometimes I want it to be okay if the User Agent doesn't match." -- Are you sure that this check is actually useful to you?

Comment: User agent checking does add absolutely *nothing* to security. If you fix your code to not enable session hijacking at all, you can just remove that check and ensure your users a better experience. If you don't, you're screwed anyways (and Russion hackers will pwn your website :)

Comment: @user1200129: because it is not a solution?

Comment: Well im on cPanel, I've never learnt SSL, is using the SSL/TLS Manager to set up SSL all it takes to have it incorporated into the website? I'd also like this user agent method to be working anyways though.

Comment: @JimmyBanks: SSL is not a thing that makes your application secured just by turning it on

Comment: @JimmyBanks: The assumption that SSL will add anything to security here is as wrong as the assumption that user agent checking will add anything to security.

Comment: Okay, I'll have to read more into SSL before I understand its application.

Comment: @NiklasB. I realize that this can be easily bypassed, it is simply one method of many that i want to have incorporated.

Comment: @NiklasB. I missed your last post, what method do you recommend for preventing session hijacking?

Comment: @JimmyBanks: No, no, no. This is not the way security works. Adding a lot of tiny obstacles will *not improve security*. It will only slow down attackers for an equally tiny amount of time. I can tell you that because I work as a security tester.

Comment: @NiklasB. Okay can you link me to a proper method that explains what will be truly effective in preventing session hijacking?

Comment: Session hijacking is prevented by proper input and output sanitization to prevent injection and XSS attacks and by securing your site against CSRF. Yeah, it's more work to find and fix your vulnerabilities than to introduce random security "measures", but it should be worth the effort. For starters, look at the [OWASP Top 10](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Category:OWASP_Top_Ten_Project) and make yourself familiar with different types of attacks. Then try to review your code if it might be vulnerable to those attacks (for example because you still don't use prepared SQL statements).

Comment: ... or because you don't properly sanitize user-provided values when outputting them as HTML etc.

Comment: @Niklas B.: I bet the question is more about what to do after session has already been hijacked, not about how to prevent the hijacking.

Comment: @zerkms: Oh that's easy, probably there is no good method to do that. IP checking *might* be viable, but it is pretty certain to kill sessions about once a day.

Comment: @Niklas B.: I do realize that, OP doesn't :-) You better write an answer about the possible solutions and mention that all of them don't give 100% result (but it worth at least adding IP check)

Comment: @zerkms: No, sorry, I think that really should be a comment. Hopefully OP will rethink his way of implementing security on his website.

Comment: @Niklas B.: Ok, as you wish ;-) But it could be a good answer OP expects to get ;-)

Comment: okay thanks guys, i have everything validated which i have done from the get-go.  I was thinking more if a person did get their hands on anothers session, i wanted ways to detect it.  Evidently, the proper way to go about this is to prevent the session hijacking in the first place. thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

The user will need to re-authenticate themselves when switching device (rather than causing the error), then you can use both authenticated `$_SESSION['HTTP_USER_AGENT']` variables to compare against on future requests.

Answer (score 1):

To hijack a session you need to know its ID. You do this either by guessing a valid session ID or by obtaining it from either the client or the server.

The former is quite easy to mitigate: the more entropy, the better. But the latter cannot be mitigated with just one measure as a session ID can be exposed/obtained on multiple ways:

- eavesdropping the communication between client and server
- leaked when transmitted via URL (HTTP referrer, log files, etc.)
- Cross-Site Scripting (XSS)

Some of these can be fixed quite easy: eavesdropping can be avoided by using a secure channel (i. e. HTTPS) and leakage via URL can be avoided by transmitting the session ID in a cookie (with both *HttpOnly* and *Secure* flag). Preventing XSS is the hardest as you have to take care of every user originated input data before returning it back to the client.

But if you do this, you’re quite well protected against Session Hijacking. At least the part you can control as an attacker could obtain the cookie directly from the browser’s cookie jar. But that’s out of your scope.

Answer (score 0):

The premise behind the question reflects a misunderstanding.

The User-agent is not an effective way to prevent session hijacking.  Any attacker worth their salt can trivially spoof their User-agent to match that of the hijacked user.  This defense is at best security through obscurity.

The proper way to prevent session hijacking is to use proper security practices, such as secure session management, site-wide SSL, CSRF protection, proper input validation and output escaping, preventing XSS, and the like.  OWASP has some excellent resources on securing web applications.